# Non-Abelian Chern-Simons path integral on a torus

Tags: path-integral, chern-simons-theory

Is it possible to exactly evaluate the Chern-Simons path integral with a non-compact gauge group (say $SU(2)$) on a torus? I am asking this because 3d gravity is an $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ Chern-Simons theory. [Maloney and Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0155) were able to evaluate the path integral of 3d gravity exactly with Brown-Henneaux boundary conditions. Their answer was one-loop exact. I'm wondering if something similar is possible in an $SU(2)$ Chern-Simons theory.

Comment: SU(2) is compact...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform So it's 'simpler', right? We know more about Chern Simons theories with compact gauge groups. I just find it surprising that we cannot evaluate the path integral with a compact gauge group while we know how to do it with a non compact one.

Comment: We know how to evaluate the path integral with compact groups, see Witten's original paper. For example on the sphere, the SU(2) partition function is nothing but $S_{00}$, equation 2.26 in that paper.

Comment: You mean the one on the Jones polynomial?

Comment: He evaluates it for $S^3$, I'm looking for the result on a solid torus.